How to fix the problem that the running time of Springboot application logs is inconsistent with the system time
I have a SprintBoot web application running on Tomcat8. Its three instances are running in different docker containers.
One day, the log time of one of the application instances changed from GMT+8 to GMT, which is an eight-hour time difference. And the time-related interfaces are abnormal.
The time-related interfaces and log times of the other two instances are all in the expected Beijing time (GMT+8).
All three instances use an external configuration center, where spring.jackson.time-zone=GMT+8, so there should be no configuration inconsistency.
I compared the relevant environment variables of the three instances and found no overriding configuration related to time TZ and timezone.
Is there any other way to locate and fix this problem? Looking forward to your reply

PS: The docker container is a centos system

